# Lower the reputation threshold for deleting closed proposals on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

The current limit is 10k, whereas the top 3 users only have 8k, 7k and 6k respectively.

We already have about 1000 proposals, a lot of them closed and so bad that they should be deleted. They're just taking space and cluttering the system.

You could make the limit 5k, or even lower.

Comment: Doesn't A51 have... *moderators*?

Comment: @Shog9 - Only the team, and, you know, they usually have better stuff to do...

Comment: What is clutter? Proposals you don't agree or something else?

Comment: @random - I don't have a personal problem with any proposal, it's just that I think that deleting the clutter would make Area 51 better - the other (good) proposals would receive a bit more attention. When I say clutter I refer to proposals that are obviously poorly defined, to point a few: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19642/web-3-0 http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19280/junk-drawer http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17732/design

Comment: @Dan: those are all closed. So no one can waste time participating in them. They might clog search results a bit, but otherwise...

Comment: @Shog9 - I know they're closed. This is what I was going for - there are some 30-40 closed proposals like those, that are clearly deletable, and that would also reduce the number of proposals someone would have to go through to find interesting ones.

Comment: But OK, it's just an idea I raised, I'd like Area 51 better if it was cleaner. If nobody would find this helpful (and thus it doesn't get upvoted), no biggie.

Comment: FWIW: there are currently 59 closed proposals on A51.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no *need* to vote to delete a closed proposal to have it removed.

As part of the routine maintenance of Area 51, proposals that have ABSOLUTELY NO ACTIVITY for a period of 30 days are subject to deletion. That means absolutely NO activity; no new questions, no comments, no voting, nothing. If a closed proposal gets no further activity, it will be deleted as part of that culling process.

Area 51 doesn't really need to have closed proposal hang around for future reference in the same way as Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange questions. The *only* reason to keep a closed proposal around is to give it a chance to be modified and possibly reopened. Barring that, **proposals will be deleted automatically when it receives no further activity as part of the normal maintenance of Area 51.**

Answer (score 3):

You're in pretty much the same boat as SO was for a long time... albeit on a much smaller scale. I don't doubt there's some cruft hanging around on A51, but I can guarantee it's nothing even *close* what's floating around on SO. And even so, deletion abilities were severely curtailed for 10K users not too long ago - it's considered dangerous to delete very many things.

The quick solution is to appoint more moderators. The long-term solution is to wait for a few users to hit 10K. Like SO in the early days, it's a reasonably safe bet that anyone with that much rep on the site is fairly invested in it. But given the ease with which you can gain rep on A51, it's probably a bad idea to lower the bar any further: the goal of the site is to create *new* sites after all, not to develop a thriving community of rep-hungry exclusionists. Unlike the sites that spring from it, there's no narrow set of "on topic" subjects for Area 51, and consequently little value to be had in creating community "janitors" to enforce them.

Comment: Actually, there is a clear set of rules - no duplication of existing sites, real viable proposals, no content violation - and I think there is value in having community 'janitors' helping to enforce them. I find the bar too high (new SE 2.0 sites have it at 2k), and also, A51 users are usually not that involved - there will be high rep users, but just a few of them, IMO.

Comment: @Dan: those are all fairly subjective criteria - and determining whether or not a proposal is "viable" is supposed to be the whole *point* of A51. But you're right in that most users aren't that involved... this doesn't strike me as an argument in favor of expedited deletion however: chances are, closed proposals get *far less* peer review on A51 than they do on other sites, simply because there are fewer users trolling through the list.

Comment: Just to mention, you do raise some good points, and thanks for the feedback. And to be clear - what I'd like is not expedited deletion, but rather *some* deletion, where there is clearly a consensus. As far as I remember, it takes 3 users to delete a proposal, and getting 3 users over 10k to agree on deleting something will take quite a while - and meanwhile A51 will keep filling with this *clutter*.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that, in about three months, there will be anything from 5 - 20 people above 10K. So this problem will resolve itself.

**Three months + later** - well I got that wrong, ironically partly due to [deleted proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74166/why-have-i-just-lost-2000-reputation-on-area-51)! =:-)