# Advanced Super Ninja Search Options do not work for stand-alone queries on Area51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, search

While trying to gauge the severity of [a problem mentioned by another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62990/lower-the-reputation-threshold-for-deleting-closed-proposals-on-area-51), I found to my dismay that the various search operators (user:, followers:, closed:, etc.) only work if other keywords are present in the query.

Examples:

- `followers:1` produces no results
- `followers:1 cheese` produces 5 results.

Naturally, such operators work just fine by themselves on the other SE sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks.

We also just added the "committers:1" advanced option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to [the lack of substring search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61935/also-search-substrings-in-area-51s-proposal-search), too.