# How to properly "link back" to original StackExchange questions when hosting a data dump from the closed Area51 proposal?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, data-dump

I have a data dump from closed Digital Preservation proposal, which is important enough for me, and I want to host it myself. However, I can't include backlinks to "original Q/A" because the pages I bookmarked now return 404s.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Though I don't know if that is the recommended/best practice, perhaps you can simply link back to the location of the data dump in this case? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787/digital-preservation perhaps?